# How does play framework store lists (for OneToMany relationships)

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

For OneToMany relationships, play framework lets the master keep a list of slaves. A list doesn't have a fixed size and can become very large, whereas the database row in which the master is stored is of a predetermined size. So, how does Play! framework store the list of slaves in the row containing the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play uses hibernate to persist, so this is a hibernate question, rather than specifically Play.

Let's say I have an Author class and a Book class, where Author has a list of Books,then the database will two tables, author and book. Where book will contain a link (author_id) to the parent.

So, hibernate stores the list in a separate list. If the list does not contain entities, so the row mapping cannot be done, I believe hibernate serialises the data as a clob, so it can store any size data.

Comment: So when I say  author1.books.add(book1), it's actually doing book1.author = author1? I'm guessing its just for the sake of convenience, i.e., instead of writing the query Select * from Book Where Author == author1, I can just say author1.books.get(0)?

Comment: you access your list in the normal java way. its only the db that links this way to be able to reconstruct the list.

Comment: I probably didn't word/frame the question properly, my bad! I was asking that when I type author.books.get(0), does the DB run the query Select * from Book Where Author.id == book.authorId?   Similarly, when I want book.author, it runs Select * from Author where Author.id == book.authorId? I.e., it links data with the foreign key, just like a regular rdbms. The list abstraction is just there so I can access these entities as fields of an object instead of having to type a query. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, i believe so. If you want to see it working in detail though, you can output the SQL to see for yourself....In application.conf, you can turn showing SQL on uncommenting `jpa.debugSQL=true`. This will give you the prepared statement queries with question marks in them. Also, Play uses Hibernate, so you can also use Hibernate properties. These can be written in application.conf directly or in a separate hibernate.properties file residing in the conf folder of your Play applicatio